# Run a function inside ajax success call back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

i have a snippet i created which checks all of the images inside a div and adds a class dependant on their size.

I have this currently on document ready and i works perfectly fine when the page is loaded.

However, im making a CMS where you can edit text on the page itself and then it updates via ajax.

The call response normally looks like:

```
success: function (response) {
    if (response.databaseSuccess) {
        $("#container #" +response.postid).load("#container #" +response.postContentID);
        $targetForm.find(".saveupdatebutton").qtip("hide");
    }
}
```

After this, the images inside the div that is loaded via the .load() function are not resized.

I have tried putting the code i use in that success response but no luck.

How should i be calling the code after the response?

Heres the code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
// check each image in the .blogtest divs for their width. If its less than X make it full size, if not its poor and keep it normal
var box = $(".blogtest");
box.find("img.buildimage").on('load', function () {
    var img = $(this),
        width = img.width();
    if (width >= 650) {
        img.addClass("buildimage-large");
    } else if (width < 500 && width > 101) {
        img.addClass("buildimage-small");
    }
    // if image is less than X, its most likely a smiley
    else if (width < 100) {
        img.addClass("buildimage-smiley");
    }
    }).filter(function () {
        //if the image is already loaded manually trigger the event
        return this.complete;
    }).trigger('load');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of jQuery you are using, you might be able to just change `.on` to `.live` like this:

```
box.find("img.buildimage").live('load', function () {
```

If that does NOT work, then you can try below. Then you'd have to do it the "right" way below:

First externalize your function for the image resizing:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // check each image in the .blogtest divs for their width. If its less than X make it full size, if not its poor and keep it normal
    var box = $(".blogtest");
    box.find("img.buildimage").on('load', imageOnload)
        .filter(function () {
            //if the image is already loaded manually trigger the event
            return this.complete;
        })
        .trigger('load');
});

function imageOnload(evt){
    var img = $(evt.currentTarget),
        width = img.width();
    if (width >= 650) {
        img.addClass("buildimage-large");
    } else if (width < 500 && width > 101) {
        img.addClass("buildimage-small");
    }
    // if image is less than X, its most likely a smiley
    else if (width < 100) {
        img.addClass("buildimage-smiley");
    }
}
```

Then, you can just add this statment in your success callback:

```
$("#container #" +response.postid).on("load", imageOnload);
```